fclose can be leak some data or is it very important?
I have the following C code that opens a file, reads a password from it, and compares it to a user-provided argument. The code never explicitly calls fclose() on the opened file. Is there any security vulnerability or other significant issue caused by not calling fclose() here ?
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE * f;
    char password[100 + 1] = {0};

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Fail.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    f = fopen('private_content', "r");
    fgets(password, 100, f) == NULL;

    if (strncmp(argv[1], password, 100) == 0) {
        ...some...stuff...
    }
    // No fclose(f) here.
}

What are the potential consequences of this omission, and does it pose a security risk ?

Why risk it by not closing the file?

@ScottHunter to know how is it important. So please humour me :)

Aside: What does this comparison do? fgets(password, 100, f) == NULL; ?

Side note: 'private_content' --> "private_content" Instead of hardcoding 100, use sizeof(buffer) as fgets(password, 100, f) uses one fewer bytes than password has (because fgets will deduct one to make space for the 0x00). Also, I'd do: password[strcspn(password,"\n")] = 0; if (strcmp(argv[1],password) == 0) and avoid strncmp

guessing, but I would guess no additional/amplified problems from failing to call fclose. The OS will close files when the process exits. I think of far greater concern is storing the password in plaintext in the file. Aside from an adversary accessing that file, they could potentially scrape memory to find it, or even use side channel attacks against strncmp (will exit as soon as comparison fails) to determine the password. Passwords should never be stored in plaintext.

Note that the command line argument is unlikely to have a newline at the end, but the line read from the file will have a newline at the end (fgets() keeps the newline if there's enough space in the string).

For "secret" data, you always want to reduce the "attack surface" and/or the "time window". When you do NOT close the file, you are creating some opportunities:

Information about the open file location may be captured in /proc/PID/fds, and attacker may learn the location of the secret file from lsof, or similar reports.
If your program dumps core (or if the attacker is able to make it dump core), the buffer for the open file is likely to contain the last read block, practically allowing anyone who can access the core file to see the password. When you close the file the buffer will be freed, and potentially "blanked" or removed from the address space (if allocated via mmap).
Similar to 2, if the attacker to debug the program - it will be very easy to locate the file buffers containing the passwords/other secrets.
If code is running in VM, the whole machine may be backed-up (including memory snapshot), and attackers who will have access to the backup will be able to retrieve the password from the machine dump.
If your program is forking/executing another program, all file descriptors will be passed to the called program - even if using setuid. If the attacker can convince the code to execute his own program as a child - he can use the open file descriptor to "rewind" to the beginning of the secret file, and re-read it.

The above code has a significant additional risk - it accepts password in argv[1] - making it possible to snap the password using 'ps -ef', /proc/ file system, and other methods - while the program is running.
Needless to say, it's a good idea to memset/memset_explicit the password buffer to 0 to prevent the password from staying in memory more than needed. The same holds for the input password in argv[1] - blank it AS SOON AS possible, or better yet, pass it via a safer mechanism.

Be aware that memset() may get optimized out.


What are the potential consequences of this omission, and does it pose a security risk ?

Consequence includes detection of the password via a memory dump.  Yes it is a security risk, even with or without calling fclose().
There are steps code can employ to reduce risks.  A usually one is to erase (zero fill/random fill/etc.) each password buffer as soon as code is done with it.
memset() is one approach, yet weak.  C23 has been updated to help reduce this risk.  See following.
Another is to avoid storing a password in memory as clear text in the first place.  This more advanced approach is not further mentioned here.

Consider how well memset() works.
fgets(password, 100, f) == NULL;
if (strncmp(argv[1], password, 100) == 0) {
  // ...some...stuff...
}
memset(password, 0, sizeof password);  // Good enough?

An optimizing compile can see memset(password, 0, sizeof password); has no visible effect on the virtual/theoretical machine and so can optimize it out.  Thus a snoopy memory scan may still find password.

An alternative is to declare password[] volatile, yet that has its issues too - passing a volatile void * to memset().
The usually solution is to code a crafted loop writing a constant byte one at a time to volatile memory.

C23 offers void *memset_explicit(void *s, int c, size_t n);

The memset_explicit function copies the value of c (converted to an unsigned char) into each of the first n characters of the object pointed to by s. The purpose of this function is to make sensitive information stored in the object inaccessible.

char password[100 + 1] = {0};
// ...
memset_explicit(password, 0, sizeof password);

